# Constructing a WifiConfiguration from a ScanResult or: Interpreting ScanResult's 'capabilities' String

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi

Do any of you Android gurus out there know of any open source code to create a [`WifiConfiguration`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html) from a given [`ScanResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#capabilities)? It would be helpful. Indeed, line 483 (/624) of my capture (mid April 2012) of the Android source of `WifiConfiguration.java` is a commented-out constructor intended to do exactly this, with a big TODO wondering whether it's worth implementing (see quote below). I motion yes, can I hear a second?

The main challenge I see (which is actually the brunt of this question) is how to interpret the ScanResult.configuration String.

1. can I expect just a simple list of things like `[WPA2-PSK-CCMP]`, `[WPS]`, etc?
2. are these strings enumerated somewhere in the docs or code base?
3. are there device/manufacturer/AP-specific strings I
   should know about?

---

From `WifiConfiguration.java` (with possible editorializing):

```
/** 
 * Construct a WifiConfiguration from a scanned network
 * @param scannedAP the scan result used to construct the config entry
 * TODO: figure out whether this is a useful way to construct a new entry.
 *   
public WifiConfiguration(ScanResult scannedAP) {
    networkId = -1; 
    SSID = scannedAP.SSID;
    BSSID = scannedAP.BSSID;
    // aaaah screw it I'm tired/lazy
}   
*/
```

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60523

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this project https://github.com/mkch/android-wifi-connecter and the following files in particular very helpful:

[Wifi.java](https://github.com/mkch/android-wifi-connecter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/farproc/wifi/connecter/Wifi.java)

[ConfigurationSecuritiesV8.java](https://github.com/mkch/android-wifi-connecter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/farproc/wifi/connecter/ConfigurationSecuritiesV8.java)

Comment: That project has moved here: https://github.com/kevin-yuan/android-wifi-connecter

Comment: Up to date links: https://github.com/kevin-yuan/android-wifi-connecter/blob/master/src/com/farproc/wifi/connecter/Wifi.java https://github.com/kevin-yuan/android-wifi-connecter/blob/master/src/com/farproc/wifi/connecter/ConfigurationSecuritiesV8.java

Comment: It's been 8 years so you get the check.